# Easy way to format blog posts in Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tinymce, ckeditor, text-editor, rich-text-editor

I've been trying to get styling working on site uncookedblog.com for hours now. I have tried using [this](https://github.com/spohlenz/tinymce-rails) TinyMCE gem, and [CKeditor](https://github.com/galetahub/ckeditor) as well as some other gems. I just can't figure this stuff out. All I want is for users to be able to format their posts, or at the very least have carriage returns recognized. Nothing complicated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Not sure what you're asking. How to use a wysiwyg editor in a rails view?

Comment: How to get a wysiwyg editor implemented into a text_area in a view. Right now if you write a post, there is no formatting at all. Just plain text ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to my question is really simple!!

To do simple formatting of text, like having carriage returns show in a text_area, just add simple_format in the view where you want the formatting to apear!

For example:

Changing

```
  <%= @article.body %>
```

to

```
  <%= simple_format @article.body %>
```

Will cause the text to show up with simple formatting!

Comment: Which editor is your answer compatible with? What makes the `simple_format` method available to use?  this TinyMCE gem, and CKeditor ?

Comment: @gwho, you don't need to use any gems. `simple_format` is a rails view helper. `simple_format` isn't for a text editor, it's just for rendering content properly. You use a regular `text_area` form field to input your text.